# This code keeps generating more than two select tags

Tags: php, smarty

here is the code:

```
{section name=k loop=$obj->mProduct.attributes}

  {* Generate a new select tag? *}
  {if $smarty.section.k.first ||
      $obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_name !==
      $obj->mProduct.attributes[k.index_prev].attribute_name}
    {$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_name}:
  <select name="attr_{$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_name}">
  {/if}

    {* Generate a new option tag *}
    <option value="{$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_value}">
      {$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_value}
    </option>

  {* Close the select tag? *}
  {if $smarty.section.k.last ||
      $obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_name !==
      $obj->mProduct.attributes[k.index_next].attribute_name}
  </select>
  {/if}

{/section}
```

I keep getting more than two select statements.

PLEASE HELP...

[image: here is the picture of the database,]

I expect:

```
Color:<select name="attr_Color">
             <option value="White">White</option>
             <option value="Black">Black</option>
            //....
         </select>
   Size:<select name="attr_Size">
            <option value="XL">XL</option>
            <option value="L">L</option>
            //....
        </select>
```

However, I am getting multiple select tags instead of just two:

```
Color: <select name="attr_Color">
       <option value="White">White</option>
</select>
Color: <select name="attr_Color">
       <option value="black">black</option>
</select>
//...
Size: <select name="attr_Size">
       <option value="l">l</option>
</select>
Size: <select name="attr_Size">
       <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
//...
```

I can solve this pretty well with PHP, however, Smarty 3 is proving stubborn. You guys should help me out here.

I might migrate to twigs for separating presentation tier from business logic.

Answer (score 0):

First, move your  tag outside of the smarty for loop.  For example:

```
{* Generate a new select tag? *}
<select name="attr_{$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_name}">

  {section name=k loop=$obj->mProduct.attributes}

    {* Generate a new option tag *}
    <option value="{$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_value}">
      {$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_value}
    </option>

  {/section}

</select>
```

This will return all attributes into one select box.  You'll still need to group by attribute name somehow. This a bit outside the scope of your question, but:

**SQL Method**
You'll need to perform a `GROUP BY` `DISTINCT` SQL query on your attribute name to find all relevant attribute types, then iterate over the values for each type.

**PHP Method**
Continue querying the same way you are now, but preprocess your data on the backend before you render it in your smarty template:

```
$attributes = array()
[for each row in sql query]
  if ($attributes[$row.name] == null) {
    $attributes[$row.name] = array()
  }
  $array_push($attributes[$row.name], $row.value)
[/end for]
```

In the end you'll have a nested for loop that does something like this (pseudo code):

```
[For each attribute_name in names]
    <select name="{attribute_name}">
      [For each attribute]
          <option value="{$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_value}">
            {$obj->mProduct.attributes[k].attribute_value}
          </option>
      [/end for (attribute)]
    </select>
[/end for (names)]
```

If needed, you could wrap the whole `<select/>` in an if statement to hide it if there are no attributes to choose from.